# Ajax-Enabled WCF Service not working when published

Tags: ajax, wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis

I do not know what category my question falls in:  programming error (on my part), or IIS error.

I have created a very simple Ajax-Enabled WCF Service from the visual studio 2010 template. Here is the code:

The CS file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class EmployeeServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    public int DoWork()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The WEB.CONFIG (as relates to WCF)

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EmployeeServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior">
     <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <services>
   <service name="EmployeeServices">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EmployeeServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="EmployeeServices" />
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

And .SVC File:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="EmployeeServices" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/EmployeeServices.cs" %>
```

Now the problem:
When I test this on my local machine in a web page with javascript that looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="EmployeeServices.svc" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pass(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        function fail(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var service = new EmployeeServices();
            service.DoWork(pass, fail, null);
        });
    </script>
</div>
</form>
```

It works fine, until I publish it to the web server. Then I get a "EmployeeServices not defined" error.

How do I troubleshoot this issue? I appreciate your help, sincerely.

Comment: what are you using as your client side javascript framework?  The Microsoft AJAX stuff?

Comment: I edited my post to show that I had dropped in a Script Manager to wire up the access to the services. However, I am using jQuery to actually write my ajax-enabled code.

Answer (score 1):

provide a namespace for your svc file like `[ServiceContract(Namespace = "namespacw")]` and the ncall service in jquery with this namespace like `<yournamespace>.service.DoWork(pass, fail, null)`.